# Does Antioxidant prevent oxidation that creates free radical?

Tags: microbiology

I have already known that antioxidant can neutralize oxidant/free-radical, but i want to know if antioxidant can also prevent the oxidation or not. I want to know to how it works if antioxidant can prevent it.

By the way, my point in asking this question is actually to answer my final question: Does vitamin C (antioxidant) inhibit the oxidation in ripening fruits?

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E From my knowledge free radicals in human body are produced as a unwanted consequence of oxidations-hydroxylations-coupled oxidation reductions etc.involving cytochromes, EC1 enzymes.If anti oxidants were to prevent them forming directly from source reactions then they would have to be inhibitors of such enzyme systems....

Comment: So, antioxidant cannot prevent the making of free radical, it cannot prevent the oxidation? okey then... thank you !

Comment: ...the second half of youre question is interesting.But ripening of fruit is usually caused by ethylene in plucked fruits mainly...but for an info I can tell u that most of the ascorbate in cut & uncovered citruses is lost because of its conversion to dehydro ascorbate...Good luck with the question

Comment: OKEEEEEEYYY...! Thanks for helping, i guess i can answer that question now :)